# Can somebody please help me with a geometric transformation problem?

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, transformation, geometric-arc

I need to draw a circular arc between two given points. I also have the arc's radius. I understand that this can be done using standard `canvas` APIs but I need to handle the case of elliptical arcs too. This code is a generalized solution. The only problem right now is that it doesn't work!

The mathematical concept behind this code is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53093/how-to-find-the-center-of-an-ellipse.

My JS code is implementation of that. My JS code can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/BkEnz/2/. Ideally both the circles there should pass through the two little pink dots.

I hope somebody can point me towards the right direction. I have been trying to solve this for past few days now!

Comment: Where is the problem? Are the calculations wrong, or you cannot draw the arc according to the outcome of the calculations?

Comment: @Vlad I am not sure but I thinks the calculations are going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Fixed it! The corrected code is at http://jsfiddle.net/ZxRBT/.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, and then accept your own answer to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue. The corrected working code is at http://jsfiddle.net/ZxRBT.

Notice the line

```
var t = translate(-R1R2x, -R1R2y, IDENTITY_TRANSFORM());
```

In my previous version of the code this line was

```
var t = translate(-R1R2x, -R1R2y, sr);
```

So when I was calculating the value of `C1` and `C2`, using the following code

```
C1 = compose(vut, [[R1x],[R1y],[1]]);
C2 = compose(vut, [[R2x],[R2y],[1]]);
```

I was also applying the `sr` composition over `R1x,R1y` and `R2x,R2y`, but these points were already in `sr` coordinate.

This was a grave mistake which I overlooked for really a long time.